# which application can I use to test on tablet my android application developed on linux os

Tags: android

I have used intellij 14 on linux os to develop an android application. I dont know which application can I use to test my application on a tablet.

I have used **Snappea** application to run an android application developed on windows os and now I dont think I can use it on linux too.

Comment: have you try `Genymotion`?

Comment: Try Genymotion..you can use this link http://www.enqlu.com/2014/03/how-to-install-genymotion-android-emulator-on-ubuntu-or-linux-mint.html